# picamera works on it's own but fails in code

Tags: python, camera

When I run the following code I can take a picture with my Raspberry Pi B

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import picamera
from time import sleep

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
camera.vflip = True
camera.iso = 400
sleep(3)
camera.capture('image.jpg')
camera.stop_preview()
```

But as soon as I try and run the code runs

```
print ("Taking pics")

now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S") #get the current date and time for the start of the filename

if config.capture_count_pics:
    try: # take the photos
        for i in range(1,total_pics+1):
            camera.hflip = True # preview a mirror image
            camera.start_preview(resolution=(config.monitor_w, config.monitor_h)) # start preview at low res but the right ratio
            time.sleep(2) #warm up camera
            #GPIO.output(led_pin,True) #turn on the LED
            filename = config.file_path + now + '-0' + str(i) + '.jpg'
            camera.hflip = False # flip back when taking photo
            camera.capture(filename)
            print(filename)
            #GPIO.output(led_pin,False) #turn off the LED
            camera.stop_preview()
            show_image(real_path + "/pose" + str(i) + ".png")
            time.sleep(capture_delay) # pause in-between shots
            clear_screen()
            if i == total_pics+1:
                break
    finally:
        camera.close()
else:
    camera.start_preview(resolution=(config.monitor_w, config.monitor_h)) # start preview at low res but the right ratio
    time.sleep(2) #warm up camera

    try: #take the photos
        for i, filename in enumerate(camera.capture_continuous(config.file_path + now + '-' + '{counter:02d}.jpg')):
            #GPIO.output(led_pin,True) #turn on the LED
            print(filename)
            time.sleep(capture_delay) # pause in-between shots
            #GPIO.output(led_pin,False) #turn off the LED
            if i == total_pics-1:
                break
    finally:
        camera.stop_preview()
        camera.close()
```

I get an error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2044, in _negotiate_format
mmal.MMAL_EINVAL, 'failed to negotiate port format')
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: failed to negotiate port format: Argument is invalid
Ended abruptly
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

and I have no idea why, or where to even begin troubleshooting

Traceback

```
    Taking pics
    mmal: mmal_vc_port_info_set: failed to set port info (3:0): EINVAL
    mmal: mmal_vc_port_set_format: mmal_vc_port_info_set failed 0x1e0a150 (EINVAL)
mmal: mmal_vc_port_info_set: failed to set port info (3:0): EINVAL
mmal: mmal_vc_port_set_format: mmal_vc_port_info_set failed 0x1e0a150 (EINVAL)
mmal: mmal_vc_port_info_set: failed to set port info (3:0): EINVAL
mmal: mmal_vc_port_set_format: mmal_vc_port_info_set failed 0x1e0a150 (EINVAL)
mmal: mmal_vc_port_info_set: failed to set port info (3:0): EINVAL
mmal: mmal_vc_port_set_format: mmal_vc_port_info_set failed 0x1e0a150 (EINVAL)
mmal: mmal_vc_port_info_set: failed to set port info (3:0): EINVAL
mmal: mmal_vc_port_set_format: mmal_vc_port_info_set failed 0x1e0a150 (EINVAL)
mmal: mmal_vc_port_info_set: failed to set port info (3:0): EINVAL
mmal: mmal_vc_port_set_format: mmal_vc_port_info_set failed 0x1e0a150 (EINVAL)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 151, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 101, in _get_module_details
    loader = get_loader(mod_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 464, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 474, in find_loader
    for importer in iter_importers(fullname):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 430, in iter_importers
    __import__(pkg)
  File "drumminhands_photobooth.py", line 371, in <module>
    start_photobooth()
  File "drumminhands_photobooth.py", line 250, in start_photobooth
    camera.start_preview(resolution=(config.monitor_w, config.monitor_h)) # start preview at low res but the right ratio
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 800, in start_preview
    self, self._camera.outputs[self.CAMERA_PREVIEW_PORT], **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/renderers.py", line 477, in __init__
    self.renderer.inputs[0].connect(source).enable()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 1296, in connect
    return other.connect(self, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 1304, in connect
    return MMALConnection(self, other, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2141, in __init__
    super(MMALConnection, self).__init__(source, target, formats)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 1986, in __init__
    self._negotiate_format(formats)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2044, in _negotiate_format
    mmal.MMAL_EINVAL, 'failed to negotiate port format')
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: failed to negotiate port format: Argument is invalid
Ended abruptly
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "drumminhands_photobooth.py", line 85, in cleanup
    pygame.quit()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'quit'
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "drumminhands_photobooth.py", line 85, in cleanup
    pygame.quit()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'quit'
```

Comment: Can you also post the traceback?

Comment: Without the full traceback I'm not sure exactly what's going on but I'll hazard a guess that `monitor_w` and `monitor_h` might not be what you're expecting when `start_preview` is called (might be worth throwing a print statement before that to check them); that's the only place that I'd expect to see that error in the posted script

Comment: I have posted the traceback.  The code that I am trying to run comes from this project on github https://github.com/drumminhands/drumminhands_photobooth

It is failing when I run the drumminhands_photobooth.py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this, by changing the config file.
Updating the hi_res_pics field from False to True, made the whole process start working.

Thanks for the help